# What is the nix-expression "<nixpkgs>"?

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

When querying for hackage packages, [the manual](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#users-guide-to-the-haskell-infrastructure) suggests using the command:

```
$ nix-env -f "<nixpkgs>" -qaP -A haskellPackages
```

Thus we define the 'active Nix expression' to be "<nixpkgs>" when searching for Haskell packages.

What does this expression "<nixpkgs>" mean and where is it defined?
I do not have a channel by that name, nor do I see it occurring in my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379654/what-does-the-nixpkgs-string-value-mean-in-nix/47388602#47388602

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `man nix-env` (and likely other sources):

```
   NIX_PATH
       A colon-separated list of directories used to look up Nix
       expressions enclosed in angle brackets (i.e., <path>). For
       instance, the value

           /home/eelco/Dev:/etc/nixos

       will cause Nix to look for paths relative to /home/eelco/Dev and
       /etc/nixos, in that order. It is also possible to match paths
       against a prefix. For example, the value

           nixpkgs=/home/eelco/Dev/nixpkgs-branch:/etc/nixos

       will cause Nix to search for <nixpkgs/path> in
       /home/eelco/Dev/nixpkgs-branch/path and /etc/nixos/nixpkgs/path.
```

On my machine, `NIX_PATH` is `nixpkgs=/Users/me/.nix-defexpr/channels/nixpkgs`, so `<nixpkgs>` refers to the `nixpkgs` channel that I am subscribed to.

In general, `<...>` causes a path to be treated not literally, but as found in some directory specified by your `NIX_PATH`.